# How to post the data into multiple tables using Talend RestFul Services

Tags: mysql, rest, talend

I have 3 tables called PATIENT, PHONE and PATIENT_PHONE.

1. The PATIENT table contains the columns: id, firstname, lastname, email and dob.
2. The PHONE table contains the columns: id, type and number.
3. The PATIENT_PHONE table contains the columns: patient_id, phone_id.

The PATIENT and PHONE tables are mapped by the PATIENT_PHONE table. So I have to join these 3 tables to post firstname, lastname, email and number fields to the database.

I tried like this:
[image: 1]

Schema for first_xmlmap
[[image: 2]]

Schema mapping for Patient and Patient_phone 
[[image: 3]]

Comment: What is the part that is not working ? Could you give more detail about your issue/error ?

Comment: I did posting for single table which is worked.  TRestRequest-->TMysqlOutput-->TxmlMap --->TRestResponse  its working  fine. Now I am want post  the data into multiple tables .I dont konw how to post to multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to write the same data to multiple database tables within the same database instance for each request against the web service.

How about using the tHashOutput and tHashInput components?

If you can't see the tHash* components in your component Pallete, go to:
File > Edit project properties > Designer > Pallete settings...

Highlight the filtered components, click the arrow to move them out of the filter and click OK.

The tHash components allow you to push some data to memory in order to read it back later. Be aware that this data is written to volatile memory (RAM) and will be lost once the JVM exits.

Ensure that "append" in the tHashOutput component is unchecked and that the tHashInput components are set not to clear their cache after reading.

You can see some simple error handling written into my example which guarantees that a client will always get some sort of response from the service, even when something goes wrong when processing the request.

Also note that writing to the database tables is an all-or-nothing transaction - that is, the service will only write data to all the specified tables when there are no errors whilst processing the request.

Hopefully this gives you enough of an idea about how to extend such functionality to your own implementation.

[image: Talend REST Web Service for writing data to multiple tables, with error handling]

Comment: Thanks  for Answer.

Comment: But I am doing Patient registration.I need to post  Patient fields to  patient  table and Address fields to address Table.  But  Both  Patient  and Address Tables are mapped by Patient_address  Table it contains Patient_id and Address_id. so I have to join these 3 tables to post the data into Patient and Address tables.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to update your question to give an example of the REST payload being posted and the schema of each table you want to write to? It's hard to visualise exactly what you mean without that information (but be sure to strip out any sensitive information before putting it up!)